# I want to select two category from redux framework but it calls one

Tags: php, wordpress

My code is below:

**Sample-config.php**

```
array(
    'id'       => 'opt-select-featured-post-3',
    'type'     => 'select',
    'data'     => 'categories',
    'title'    => __( 
        'Select Category 3rd Columns', 
        'redux-framework-demo' 
     ),
 ),
```

**Template-home.php**

```
<?php $my_query = new WP_Query('category_name='.get_cat_name($arefin030201['opt-select-featured-post-3']).'&showposts=1&order=DESC&orderby=id'); ?>
<?php while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>

<h3><?php the_title() ?></h3>

<?php the_content() ?><br><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">more info</a> 

<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

So if you want to select multiple categories, set multi=>true to your select option. Then you will be provided with the category IDs and you can query accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the [Category Parameters for WP_Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Category_Parameters) and pass several categories as an array, if you can/want to change that part of the template.

```
$query = new WP_Query( 'cat=2,6,17,38' );
```